# Get distance between two location in java android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I know that I can get distance with google api and it is very good

But is it slow sometimes and not possible for my app

Is there any way to get distance between two location?

Comment: If it is slow, it's either because your app is slow or because your network is slow. It is very unlikely that Google's api are too slow for your app

Comment: @ArthurAttout Thanks.yes i am stupid that why google's api is slow,how is it affecting my app on google's api speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many search and faq,Finally I understood that google's api is best and first way to get distance two location

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Location.distanceBetween()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) or [Location.distanceTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location))

Comment: Location.distanceBetween() or Location.distanceTo() get distance directly two location but i need to real distance two location

Comment: I am not getting your point what do you mean by real distance?

Comment: If by real distance you mean distance by road, then even if you find it slow I think it is simpler to use Google API. You'll need Google API to get road information anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily get the `lastKnownLocation`, add the co-ordinates to an `ArrayList` and then measure the distance between the points in that list as shown below:

**Prerequisites**:

Add permissions to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Import Gradle Dependencies:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
```

Add this class to your project:

[Github: android-maps-utils : SphericalUtil.java](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java)

Implement `LocationListener` in your `Activity`:

```
public class myClass extends Activity implements LocationListener {
```

Define your global Variables:

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
private ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Get Initial Location (in `onCreate()` or `onClick()`):

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
// default
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if (coordList != null && !coordList.isEmpty()) {
    coordList.get(0);
} else {
    coordList.add(0, new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
}

if (location != null) {
   onLocationChanged(location);
}

getLocationUpdates();
```

create a `getLocationUpdates()` method:

```
 private void getLocationUpdates() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            checkPermission();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, ONE_SECOND, ONE_METER, this);
        }
    }
```

Request location updates from your `locationManager` (make sure you [requestPermission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for Android 6.0 and up)

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getLocationUpdates();
    }
```

Use the `SphericalUtil` class to compute the distance within the `ArrayList` inside the `onLocationChange` function.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double distance = SphericalUtil.computeLength(coordList);
        distance = round(distance, 2) / 1000;
        distanceOutput.setText(distance + "km");
    }
```

Add the round functionality:

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

This will get the distance between start and end points in km and round it down to two decimal places, feel free to convert them into any other unit of distance depending on your use-case.

Comment: Is it accurate?

Comment: It's accurate for me, yes. The feature i've used it for is counting steps and logging the walk on a GoogleMaps Fragment in real-time (which is in production currently). you'll have to test different things such as how often the onLocationChange is called to match what you want using the requestLocationUpdates method, i'm currently updating the method every meter the user walks. You may want something different.

Comment: It does depend on the users signal strength though, but it's not caused many problems for me thus far.

Comment: A point for you.I have only two location for get distance that google's api can get distance between two location

Answer (score 0):

Google Distance matrix API need to use for the correct distance between places.

Comment: I think it is the API that @Frank finds too slow.

Comment: It is slow sometimes